# Converting assembly instructions to hexadecimal format?

Tags: assembly, arm, armv7, machine-code

This is homework, so I'd rather be pushed in the right direction than spoon-fed the answer.

Task: Give binary and hexadecimal encodings for the following instructions

```
SBC R0, R12, R6
```

Using some instructions from the professor, I've been able to break some of this down into what I think is the correct binary format:

```
Cond  000  Op    S  Rn    Rd    00000000  Rm
----  ---  ----  -  ----  ----  --------  ----
1110  000  0110  0  1100  0000  00000000  0110
```

**Here are my questions:**
1) When is the S flag `1` rather than `0`? How can I tell if the flag should be `1` or `0` just based on the given Assembly code?

2) How do you determine, with just the Assembly code given, whether it is I-type or R-type?

3) Why are the 3-bit `000` and 8-bit `00000000` fields constant?

EDIT: The processor is ARMv7

Comment: What kind of processor is this for?

Comment: Should be ARM7, edited the question to include it

Comment: Take a look at page 10 of this [pdf](http://vision.gel.ulaval.ca/~jflalonde/cours/1001/h17/docs/arm-instructionset.pdf) :)

Comment: Did you mean ARMv7 (the last 32-bit-only version of the architecture) or ARM7 (the very old CPU)?  I tagged ARMv7, although it probably doesn't matter since I'd guess that all ARM CPUs have sub-with-carry.

Answer (score 4):

Using this [PDF](http://vision.gel.ulaval.ca/~jflalonde/cours/1001/h17/docs/arm-instructionset.pdf) as a reference, one finds the format for the data processing instructions in section 4.5

<sub>Click image to enlarge</sub>
[image: Data processing instruction]

Remember that the assembly syntax for instructions like `sbc` is `<opcode>{cond}{S} Rd,Rn,<Op2>` and `<Op2>` is `Rm{,<shift>}` or `,<#expression>`

**Bits 31 - 28**

These four bits are the conditional code that predicates the instruction.
If no conditional code suffix is specified in the instruction then `AL` (always) is implied.
`AL` is coded as 1110.

**Bits 27 - 25**

The first two bits are always 0 for data processing instruction.
The lowest bit is 1 if an immediate is used as second operand or 0 if a register is used.
Since `r6` is the second operand, these three bits are all zero.

**Bits 24 - 21**
This is the opcode, 0110 for `sbc`.

**Bit 20**
This corresponds to the *S* suffix of the assembly syntax.
If set the instruction sets the flags, otherwise they are unchanged.

**Bits 19 - 16**
This is the first operand register *Rn*, it is  `r12` and thus this field values  1100.

**Bits 15 - 12**
This is the destination operand register *Rd*, it is `r0` and thus 0000 must be used for this field.

**Bits 11 - 0**
This field is interpreted based on the value of bit 25 (bit *I*).
When I = 0, this fields is

**Bits 11 - 4**
Shift amount.
Since no shift is specified in the assembly instruction, these bits are 0.

**Bits 3 - 0**
Second operand register *Rm*, this is `r6` so 0110 is the right value.

---

You'll need to remember for each instruction what type of format it uses.
There is a lot of structure, patterns arise and general categories (like "data processing instructions") can be defined but ultimately there is also a mnemonic effort (e.g. the opcode values, the bit fields, etc...)